# How to convert rows of sqlite data to a ArrayList<double[]>()?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, charts

I get the data type of data from sqlite database is string. How to put these data into ArrayList()? Thank you!

Comment: But I think I need to put into ArrayList<double[]>(). Is it possible?

Comment: It is because I use this array list for a line chart using achartengine

Comment: The array list is used to determine the position

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        Levels l = new Levels(getBaseContext()); // level ur table name
        l.open();
        Cursor c_l = l.selectAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < c_l.getCount()+1; i++)
        {
            array.add(c_l.getString(0)); // getstring 0 means your column 
        }
        c_l.close();
        l.close();
```